# Grep JSON code blocks

Tags: json

Hi I have a rather long JSON file that has a bunch of entries such as:

```
    {
Title: ABC123
Date: 583838484483
User: ABC33333
},
...etc
```

what I'm looking for is to be able to grep for a string and if its contained anywhere within that code block the entire block is returned. Any help you can give?

Alright, I think I'm half way there, so I can get awk to print between {} but now how do I get it to also print each block to its own file?

```
cat all.txt  /{/ , /},/ { print $0 }>test.txt
```

Comment: You could try just using the context options if you want an approximate answer (`-C<n>` to show `n` lines before and after)

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep with --before-context and --after-context options like:

```
grep --before-context=5 --after-context=5 "User: ABC33333" file.json
```

Comment: Thanks but if what I'm grepping for happens to be in the last line I would want all the lines above it and not x lines below as well since that would cut into the next code block which might not be a match.

Comment: How big is the file? You could try loading it into a javascript array and select the objects that match the conditions you want. Another option could be to load that json object into a database and query it for the records, then write those to json.